# how to return the original value first?

Tags: java

How can I return the value I input when I first call stream.next()?

```
> StringStream stream= new StringStream("pez");
> stream.next()
"pfa"
> stream.next()
"pfb"
```

for instance, when I first call stream.next(), it should be "pez",and "pfa" should appear until the second time I call stream.next().

```
import java.io.*;

    //the class produces a continuous sequence of strings that consist of lower case letters.

    public class StringStream extends stream {
      //@param FirtsV is the first value we input
      private String FirstV;

      //the constructor that represents the first value returned by the stream.
      public StringStream(String FirstV) {
        this.FirstV = FirstV;
      }

      //the method returns the next value of the stream.
      public String next() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(FirstV);
        int l = sb.length();
        if(sb.charAt(l-1) < 'z') {
          sb.setCharAt(l-1, (char)(sb.charAt(l-1) + 1));
          FirstV = sb.toString();
        }else{
          if(sb.charAt(l-1) == 'z') {
            sb.setCharAt(l-1, 'a');
            sb.setCharAt(l-2, (char)(sb.charAt(l-2) + 1));
            FirstV = sb.toString();
        }
      }
       return FirstV;
      }

      @Override
      public String data() {
        return FirstV;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your next() method by adding the following line at the start:

```
String originalV = FirstV;
```

Then change your return statement to

```
return originalV;
```